# Remove characters in string?

Tags: c#, string

Here is my string:

```
[{"url":"http:\/\/is1.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/47\/20\/1f\/47201fb7-ddbf-2ff9-767d-4e26065d0158\/source\/600x600bb.jpg"
```

Here is what I need:

```
http:\/\/is1.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/47\/20\/1f\/47201fb7-ddbf-2ff9-767d-4e26065d0158\/source\/600x600bb.jpg
```

I am positive I use the following to remove the quotation marks:

```
s = s.Replace("\"", "");
```

But how would I remove:

```
[{"url":
```

I think I would use something like:

```
int index = sourceString.IndexOf(removeString);
string cleanPath = (index < 0)
    ? sourceString
    : sourceString.Remove(index, removeString.Length);
```

but for some reason I cannot add it to here due to it itself using double quotes.

Comment: It looks like a Json string, so why not use a library like `Json.NET` to get the element value?

Comment: Why not use `Replace("[{\"url\":", "")`?

Comment: I didn't know how to add in the filter, thank you Jorgel!

Comment: @Shrooms - Please don't be rude to Kane. He's correct, you are trying to get the element value. In this case the element value **is** the URL.

Comment: Remember that after replacing the " with nothing, they are no longer around the "url" !

Comment: @Jorgel, your filter doesn't work!

Comment: If your string is actually JSON then it should also end in `}]`. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Replace()` again on your `[{"url":`, just remember that you removed the `"` on the first `Replace`, so it is now only `[{url:`

```
s = s.Replace("\"","");
s = s.Replace("[{url:", ""); // s no longer has " after the first Replace
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't using any JSON libraries and just getting the property url value then why not keep it simple with `string.IndexOf()` and ignore the first and last char?

```
var idx = rawJSON.IndexOf(':');
if ( idx > -1 )
{
   return rawJSON.SubString(idx + 2, rawJSON.Length - (idx + 2 + 1));  //calculating in my head....
}
else
{
   return rawJSON;
}
```

Comment: the only thing i'm unsure of is the second param to the SubString().. i always have to have an example and figure out how many chars i deduct from the length..

Answer (score 1):

This works a treat:

```
var s = @"[{""url"":""http:\/\/is1.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music6\/v4\/47\/20\/1f\/47201fb7-ddbf-2ff9-767d-4e26065d0158\/source\/600x600bb.jpg""}]";

var jarray = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s) as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray;
var url = jarray[0].Value<string>("url");
```

I get:

> http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/47/20/1f/47201fb7-ddbf-2ff9-767d-4e26065d0158/source/600x600bb.jpg

You just need to NuGet "Newtonsoft.Json" to get the library in.

Comment: The point is to use the **Newtonsoft.Json** library. It is designed to properly extract the URL from your input string. That's what it's good at. The answer you've selected doesn't actually return the right thing if there is a `}]` at the end. And do you really want the `\/` instead of `/` throughout the URL?

Comment: I need / throughout the URL but cannot use the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: @Shrooms - But you don't need `\/` throughout - so you need to remove the backslash. Why can't you use the Newtonsoft library?